# How would I make my discord bot say a message in a DIFERENT channel with a command using Hikari

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to make my Hikari bot use commands to say the message I input in the command to another/diferent channel. Basically, I want to make the bot say my messages in another channel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the ID of the channel you would like to send the message to, you can use the [`create_message`](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/rest.html#hikari.impl.rest.RESTClientImpl.create_message) method of the bot's [`RestClientImpl`](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/rest.html#hikari.impl.rest.RESTClientImpl) instance:

For Example:

```py
await bot.rest.create_message(channel_id, "foo")
```

The above would send a message with content `foo` to the channel with the given `channel_id`.